# 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I'm following a course where I have to convert a date to a unix timestamp.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print type(df.iloc[-1].name)
```

**class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'**

```
ts = df.iloc[-1].name.timestamp()
```

**AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'**

Comment: Seems like the `Timestamp` class doesn't provide a `timestamp()` method. Is it supposed to?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Hi - did either my response or @MaxU's response help so solve your problem? If so, it would be great if you could mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually ask a question (tip for next time: be more explicit), but I assume you want an epoch / Unix timestamp from a Pandas Timestamp object.

If you use the `pandas.tslib.Timestamp.value` method, you'll return the timestamp in microseconds (1/1,000,000 second):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: date_example = pd.to_datetime("2016-06-21")

In [3]: type(date_example)
Out[3]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [4]: date_example.value
Out[4]: 1466467200000000000
```

If you prefer you can simply divide by 1000 to get milliseconds or 1000000 to get whole seconds, eg:

```
In [5]: date_example.value / 1000000
Out[5]: 1466467200000
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do it this way:

generate sample DF with datetime dtype

```
In [65]: x = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='5D', periods=5)})

In [66]: x
Out[66]:
        Date
0 2016-01-01
1 2016-01-06
2 2016-01-11
3 2016-01-16
4 2016-01-21
```

convert datetime to UNIX timestamp

```
In [67]: x.Date.astype(np.int64) // 10**9
Out[67]:
0    1451606400
1    1452038400
2    1452470400
3    1452902400
4    1453334400
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```